# Do something when Apigility db-connected actions ocurr using Zend Events

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-routing

I need to do some action once my Apigility db-connected rest service is called (for example the one that creates an entity). I want to do this with Zend Events but I don't know where to start because Apigility has created no code that I can see. Please if someone could provide an example on how to do this that would be great. I'm new to Zend and Apigility.
Thanks in advance
Alejandro

Comment: Apigility create modules in the module directory of ZF2, you can there modify the code as you wish. To use events I suggest you to attach an event in Module.php onBoostrap event, and trigger it when you call the rest service, [how to use an event manager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) and [more advanced usage](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/zend-framework-2-register-event-listeners-in-configuration-file/)

Comment: That's the thing, in Apigility when creating a DB-Connected rest service it creates only two classes EntityNameCollections and EntityNameEntity, wich have no code, so I don't know wich event or method to trigger. I could create my own Resource class but I don't know if it will substitute the actions that apigility is doing.

Comment: In all case, your API is stuctured like a standard zf2 module, with module.config.php, Module.php. your entity and collection are on the 'model' layer and should contain business logic (you have to add manually because apigility can no guess if you have special logic to implement. By the way, the framework has to load the module, to do so, Module.php is called, you can attach event there, then trigger them in entity or whatever class you want to you. ZF2 triggers mvc events to return a Response object.

Comment: What mvc event should I use ?

Comment: I suppose MvcEvents::ROUTE should be fine, with low priority so that you can check the route called and test if it is your rest service. If  it is the case, then do your action. I will post an exemple in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code exemple to attach a logic to a MvcEvent

In module/APIName/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace APIName;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBoostrap($e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager      = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($event) use($serviceManager){
            $route  = $event->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            // Do some stuff, tests, etc...
        }, -1100); // set low priority to be sure that route is defined
    }
}
```

Your event will be automatically triggered by the Framework when routing.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked, now my only doubt is how to differentiate the exact route, for instance: /something from /something/2, and if it is GET or POST